# How to run a request only once with many iterations in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I tried to look everywhere, but no luck so far. I have a collection with 6 requests that run automatically, but I need the last request to run only once at the end of the last iteration.
I tried to use this code in Pre-request Script of Request 5

```js
if (pm.info.iteration === 0) {
    postman.setNextRequest("Request 6")
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest("Request 1")
}
```

and expected that the Request 6 would run only once after there is no more iteration to run, but I am doing something wrong since it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

you kind of mixed up `pm.info.iterationCount` and `pm.info.iteration`:

- `pm.info.iteration` The value of the current iteration
- `pm.info.iterationCount` The total number of iterations that are scheduled to run

See the documentation: [Scripting with request info](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-with-request-info)

You want to execute "Request 6" at the very end, this means, when `iteration` and `iterationCount` are equal.

Note that `iteration` start at 0, so you need to add `+ 1` when comparing it to `iterationCount`.

Also, if this condition does not match, you need to set the nextRequest to `null`.
"Request 1" will be executed automatically by the Collection Runner. If you set the nextRequest to "Request 1", you will end up in an endless loop.

The following will do you what you want, you can put it as pre-request script or test of "Request 5".

```js
if (pm.info.iterationCount == pm.info.iteration + 1) {
    postman.setNextRequest("Request 6")
} else {
    postman.setNextRequest(null)
}
```